# Annoying streaks across rendered objects in Mayavi2

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, mayavi

Whenever I render a surface in Mayavi with an opacity < 1, I can see annoying streaks in the rendered object in some camera view.

For example, the following screenshot of the contour3d plot example from http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.contour3d shows the annoying (horizontal) streaking near the bottom of the blue ellipsoid shape.

How can I eliminate or reduce this artifact?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a consequence of the way alpha rendering works. However, using lower opacity values will probably reduce the artifact.

Comment: I have tried lower opacity values too without success. I have also spent some time experimenting with the different parameters of the surface actor without any success. I have experienced this artifact several times with other visualizations in Mayavi, but I decided to use this example as this example is from the Mayavi tutorial. I wonder if this is an issue that only I am seeing (i.e. related to the graphics card in my computer ... I have a dedicated graphics card from NVIDIA) or not. If this is a common issue, I wonder why it has not bothered anyone else?